# KendoReact and react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, kendo-react-ui

I am having trouble using [KendoReact](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/) components with the [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) library:

```
<Controller
   as={Input}
   name="firstName"
   control={control}
   defaultValue="type something here"
/>
```

[Stackblitz sample here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-zre9e1?file=index.tsx)

The react-hook-form [sample](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#ControlledInput) is using MaterialUI components to show third-party libraries integration and that appears to be working properly. When using the Kendo Input component, typing anything in the input control results in the control showing `[object Object]` instead of the typed value. That's because the value that gets to be set on the control is the `event` object instead of the actual value.

I can't find a way around this, hopefully somebody else did find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a simple wrapper around the Input to get the value from `onChange` would work:

```
const InputWrapper = props => {
  return <Input {...props} onChange={e => {
    props.onChange(e.target.value)
  }} />
}

...

  <Controller
    as={InputWrapper}
    name="firstName"
    control={control}
    defaultValue="type something here"
  />
```

[stackblitz](https://react-ts-5o2maw.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Had to create the wrapper as `function InputWrapper(props) { ... }`, but that did it. Thank you!